# crontab is not running my script

Tags: macos, unix, cron

I'm new to cron jobs. I read a [post](http://broadcasterproject.wordpress.com/) on how to write a cron job with crontab.
So my crontab looks like this:

`1 * * * * /Users/apple/Desktop/wget/down.sh`

which basically means that every minute i want to execute the script :*down.sh*. Now the script runs 
fine manually. The script is a simple program that downloads a PDF from the internet:

`#!/bin/bash`

`wget -U Mozilla -t 1 -nd -A pdf "http://www.fi.usj.edu.lb/images/stories/HoraireS08/3eli.pdf" -e robots=off;`

I don't know why it's not running every minute once the terminal tells me that he's installing the new crontab.

Can somebody help me please?

Solution:
Thank you all for your help, the syntax as **mcalex** said should be 
* */1 * * * path/to/script
if you want it to be executed every hour.
The cron job was working normally.However my mistake was simply writing permissions, in fact while executing the wget command, it's supposed to write the pdf file in the current workind directory which is a system directory in case of the cron tab. so i solved my problem simply by navigating to the Desktop directory before executing the wget command like so:

`cd /Users/apple/Desktop/wget`

and then do whatever i want to do.
PS: i should include the full path of the wget command too.

Thank you all for you help again:)

Comment: How often does it run?  Also, when you run it manually, how long does the task take?

Comment: @mcalex It doesnt run at all, and manually the script is executed almost immediatly.

Comment: Schedule syntax for every *hour* is `0 * * * *`, and `* * * * *` for every *minute*. (for the record)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Do you have a typo?  It looks like you might have mis-typed Desktop?

Another thing to do is to redirect the output of running the script to a file so you can see what's going on like this:

1 * * * * /Users/apple/Destop/wget/down.sh >> /tmp/cron.out

and then check out the file to see what's going on.

Comment: this will redirect only stdout. if you want errors as well do this: ..down.sh >> /tmp/cron.out 2>&1

Comment: Note that `1****` will be "the first minute", not every minutes

Answer (score 17):

When you put 1 in the first column, it will run on the first minute (of every hour).  In order to get it to run in every minute of every hour, you need to set the minute column as */1

So your line should read:

```
*/1 * * * * /Users/apple/Desktop/wget/down.sh
```

supporting links:
job every minute:     https://bbs.archlinux.org/viewtopic.php?id=59180
job every 5 minutes:  http://www.thegeekstuff.com/2011/07/cron-every-5-minutes/

Comment: @Elie you should accept this answer since it was the solution you were looking for

Comment: You don't need to put `1`. `* * * * *` is the same as `*/1 * * * *`.

Comment: No, forget all that, To execute every minute it's just `* * * * * cmd`

Answer (score 7):

1 * * * * /Users/apple/Destop/wget/down.sh

From this entry script will never run on every minute because it will run on first minute of every hour.

Make this change to your crontab file to run this script every min.

"* * * * * /Users/apple/Destop/wget/down.sh"

Answer (score 4):

- Did cron send you some email detailing what went wrong?
- Does the script under that path exist?
- Note that cron uses `/bin/sh` to execute commands.
- Did you set a proper `PATH` in your script? `wget` may not be in the default `PATH` or there may be no `PATH` at all. Try using `/path/to/wget` in the script.

Note that downloading the same PDF file once a minute is probably a silly idea, though...

Answer (score 4):

If your cronjob is writing things to disk then be careful that system preference "Put hard disk to sleep when possible" is unchecked.

This was preventing my cronjob backup tasks to execute.