# crontab Mac running a Python script everyday at the same time

Tags: python, cron

Tried to follow the instructions from this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13280699/crontab-is-not-running-my-script) but it didn't work with me. As background info I can tell you that there's an instance of Python 2.7 installed on Mac by default and my instance is actually python 3.6, hence the Python3. I'm doing something wrong but I can't figure out what. I know that as is it will run every minute, I just want to make it work first and then change the time.

`* * * * * cd /User/Users/cannopy/PycharmProjects/untitled python3 /User/Users/cannopy/PycharmProjects/untitled/test.py`

EDIT:

After changing some things I managed to make it work with this:

```
* * * * * cd /Users/cannopy/PycharmProjects/untitled/ && ~/PycharmProjects/untitled/venv/bin/python test.py
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try,
`* * * * * cd /User/Users/cannopy/PycharmProjects/untitled && python3 test.py >> cron_result.txt`

Comment: Tried using your solution combined with @tripleee location info and managed to make it work. Thanks

Comment: Then please mark one of the answers as accepted, or post an answer of your own and accept that. Your question should remain strictly a question.

Answer (score 0):

A `crontab` entry can only contain a single line. You can combine commands with `;` or `&&` but ideally your Python script should not require to run in a particular directory.

If the script requires imports or data files from the directory where it is installed, maybe have it examine `sys.argv[0]` to discover its location.